# setState did not accept dynamic value in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have few states like

```
this.state = {
   abc1,
   abc2,
   abc3
}
```

Why I can't setState dynamically? like

```
handleDiscount = (count) => {
        this.setState({
            `abc${count}`: `!this.state.abc${count}`
        });
    }
```

Where count is 1 / 2 / 3.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are using a template string for an object property declaration; it's a syntax error. Even so, you couldn't set the template string to a variable and use that, either:

```
let count = 2;
let bar = `baz${count}`;
// This will set foo.bar, not foo.baz2
let foo = {
  bar: count
};
```

What you can do is use ES6 [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names):

```
let count = 2;
let bar = `baz${count}`;
// This will set foo[<value of bar>], i.e. foo.baz2
let foo = {
  [bar]: count
};
```

And this also works with template strings:

```
let count = 2;
// This will set foo[<template string evaluated>], i.e. foo.baz2
let foo = {
  [`baz${count}`]: count
};
```

Also, the template string in your value is wrong. That will not evaluate the property in `this.state`, instead, it will be the string e.g. `"!this.state.abc2"`. `!this.state` is code, not a string. You need this:

```
!this.state[`abc${count}`]
```

That being said, whenever setting React state based on the previous state, you should invoke setState with a function instead, from [React docs on setState](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

> [...] If the next state depends on the previous state, we recommend
>   using the updater function form, instead:
>
> ```
> this.setState((prevState) => {
>   return {counter: prevState.quantity + 1};
> });
> ```

So, to summarize, this should do the trick:

```
handleDiscount = (count) => {
  this.setState((prevState) => {
    return { [`abc${count}`]: !prevState[`abc${count}`] }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get property of the target object please use `target["string property name"]` [bracket syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation).

As for adding dynamic property to object you should use `{ ["string property name"]: value }` [computed property name  syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names).

Your fixed code should look like this:

```
handleDiscount = (count) => {
  this.setState({
    [`abc${count}`]: !this.state[`abc${count}`]
  });
}
```

[Please see working example here](https://jsfiddle.net/wbqvobhn/).

As a side note, you should really check [Linus' answer regarding React's `setState` behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43657364/1384679).

Answer (score -1):

That's not how you dynamically set object properties. That's template literals.

```
handleDiscount = (count) => {
    this.setState({
        abc[count]: !this.state.abc[count]
    });
}
```

But you can't do that with array indexes anyway

Comment: abc[count] = abc.1 where 1 ==count.